# php request to display datas from a webpage

Tags: php, request, html

I'm a teacher in a primary school et we're part of the weatherstation project with raspberry pi
we have a website with our measurements : http://meteovictorhugo.ddns.net:1800/demo
everything is working.
Now, we'd like to have measurements from other stations in the world tu study them and work in sciences, geography...
We can have them here : https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/raspberrypi/weatherstation/getalllastmeasurement
but it's not really readable for pupils

First, we would like to extract datas to put them in a table and in a second time be able to choose which station we want to display

It's a bit difficult for us

All I succeed to do is this :

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/raspberrypi/weatherstation/getalllastmeasurement');
$json = utf8_encode($json);
$obj = var_dump(json_decode($json));

echo $obj;
```

which gives us, meteovictorhugo.ddns.net:1800/demo/world.php so as to say nothing ...

If someone has an idea, we will be very grateful and you'll help pupils (and their teacher) to learn things

I also try with this

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/raspberrypi/weatherstation/getalllastmeasurement');
$json = utf8_encode($json);
$obj = var_dump(json_decode($json));

foreach ($obj->items as $value) {
    $ground_temp = isset($value->humidity) ? $value->humidity : 'N/A';
    echo $value->weather_stn_name . ' : ' . $ground_temp . '<br/>';
}
?>
```

which gives this :  meteovictorhugo.ddns.net:1800/demo/world4.php

Thank you

jerome

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to utf8_encode the string:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/raspberrypi/weatherstation/getalllastmeasurement');
$decodedData = json_decode($json, true);

print_r($decodedData); // prints all data as array
print_r($decodedData['ground_temp']); //access ground_temp temperature key
```